# ¿Por qué no encuentra el archivo parser.h?

Tags: c

He diseñado un sencillo *header* llamado ***parser.h*** y cuyo **código** es:

```
#define MaxLinea 25
#define MaxFields 15

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int parser(FILE * file);
```

También tengo un programa ***main.c*** el cual presenta el siguiente **código**:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <parser.h>
#include <parser.c>

int main (int argc, char *argv[]){
        FILE *file;
        if(argc == 2){
            file = fopen(argv[1],'r');
            parser(file);
        }
        return 1;
}
```

He tratado de simplificar el código lo máximo posible, así que os explico cómo quería **estructurar los archivos**:

**(1)** El programa *main.c* controla el hilo principal, haciendo las llamadas pertinentes.

**(2)** El programa *parser.h* sirve de cabecera para *parser.c*.

**(3)** El programa *parser.c* sirve de apoyo para *main.c* (pues dentro tiene una función auxiliar para *main.c*).

**Así, *main.c* llama a *parser.h* y *parser.c*, y *parser.c* llama a *parser.h*.**

Sin embargo, al ejecutar la compilación mediante el comando *gcc -Wall -Wextra -o main main.c* salta el siguiente (y único) **error de compilación**:

main.c:3:10: fatal error: parser.h: No such file or directory
#include <parser.h>
^~~~~~~~~~
compilation terminated.

**Tengo los tres archivos en el mismo *path* y solo pretendo compilar *main.c***. No he compilado el resto porque tengo entendido que solo se compilan los archivos ".c", mientras que los ".h" son, por así decir, información para los módulos ejecutables (los ".c") y, por ello, no se van a ejecutar, es decir, no necesitan compilación. Compilar un ".h", sin embargo, tampoco cambia las cosas (también lo intenté y nada). Por otra parte, compilar *parser.c* no sé si debería hacerlo o no, pero es indiferente para el error de compilación que salta, pues no llega siquiera a tratar con *parser.c* la compilación.

¿Cómo incluyo entonces los archivos ".h" al main? ¿Debería compilar también *parser.c* con el mismo comando que *main.c* o tiene un tratamiento especial? Gracias.

Comment: 2 Cosas. Lo primero, si haces `#include <>` usa paths absolutos, unos include paths que ya tiene guardado el compilador, y las los que puedes añadir usando el flag `-I`. Para lo que tu quieres es mejor que uses paths relativos. Si haces `#include "parser.h"` buscara en el directorio donde tienes el archivo, que es lo que tu quieres. Lo segundo es que hacer `include` a archivos `.c` esta mal. No hay ningún motivo por el que deberías incluirlos en `main.c`, y hacerlo de ese modo te traera problemas en el futuro. La forma correcta de incluirlo es al compilar.

Comment: Tienes que añadir `parser.c` a los archivos que le pasas a `gcc`. Tu comando quedaria `gcc -Wall -Wextra -o main main.c parser.c`

Comment: Ambos comentarios aportan información que pondré aprueba seguramente mañana. Les comentaré si, finalmente, el problema de compilación se resuelve o no. Gracias y mañana vuelvo a la carga.

Comment: Efectivamente, mi problema ha quedado solucionado. @Pablochaches, puedes publicar tu respuesta si quieres para seleccionarla como solución y zanjar así la pregunta. Gracias

Comment: Listo. Añadí un detalle que se olvido en el comentario original.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## `#include<>` vs `#include""`

Si utilizas `<>` en el `include`, el compilador usara paths absolutos. Estos
son unos que ya tiene guardado el compilador. En ellos encontraras los archivos
de la librería estándar como `stdio.h`. A estos paths puedes añadir usando el
flag `-I`.

Para que tu programa compile, tendrías que añadir al include path el directorio
donde estas trabajando. Tendrías que añadir a los flags `-I.` (Recuerda que `.`
representa el directorio actual). Esto lo harías en caso de que añadieras
alguna librería a tu código, pero para el caso de uso actual hay una mejor
solución.

Si usas `""` en el `include`, el compilador usara paths relativos. Esto
significa que va a buscar los archivos en el directorio en el que estés
trabajando (Y en caso de que no los encuentre, usara los paths absolutos).

En este caso, la mejor opción seria cambiar:

```c
#include <parser.h>
#include <parser.c>
```

Por:

```c
#include "parser.h"
#include "parser.c"
```

## Incluir un `.c`?

Tu programa debería funcionar con el cambio anterior, pero no es una buena
solución.

Lo que tienes que incluir (que es lo que ponemos en los `.h`) son las
declaraciones (los `struct`, las firmas de las funciones, constantes, etc...).
Pero nunca tienes que incluir las implementaciones (que es lo que ponemos en
los `.c`), ya que esto puede ser problemático <sup>1</sup>.

Y entonces como incluyo las implementaciones de las funciones? Fácil, le pasas
el archivo al compilador:

```
gcc -Wall -Wextra -o main main.c parser.c
```

Y como una nota. Conforme mas archivos le vas añadiendo, mas tedioso se vuelve
el añadirlos todos al compilador. Y si los compilas todos, todo el tiempo, el
proceso de compilar se empieza a volver lento. Seria un buen momento para
iniciar a aprender a usar herramientas como `make`.

## `include` guards

Esto es mas una nota que un problema. Mencionas:

> Así, main.c llama a parser.h y parser.c, y parser.c llama a parser.h.

Si te das cuenta, aquí pararías incluyendo `parser.h` 2 veces, cuando en
realidad solo lo necesitas 1 vez. Para archivos tan pequeños no suele ser un
problema, pero los headers van creciendo en tamaño, y cuando son bastantes (y se
necesitan para otros headers) suman al tiempo de compilación. Para solucionar
eso puedes hacer un check al principio del header.

```c
#ifndef PARSER_H
#define PARSER_H

// ...
// Contendido
// ...

#endif
```

Tienes que tener cuidado que lo que definas no sea un nombre común, o algo que
ya se pudo haber definido. Personalmente para esto me gusta seguir la guía de
estilo de
[Google](https://google.github.io/styleguide/cppguide.html#The__define_Guard).

---

---

**1:** A excepción de las funciones marcadas con `static` o `inline`, estas si
las puedes incluir. Sobre el porque puede ser problemático,  lo entenderás
mejor conforme vayas añadiendo mas archivos, ya que tarde o temprano,
terminaras definiendo la función en 2 lugares.